# Android NDK - How to typecast object class

Tags: android, c++, android-ndk

I have very simple requirement.

Java :

```
HttpURLConnection conn = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
```

I want to achieve the same in NDK/C++.

```
jmethodID openConnMethod = env->GetMethodID(URLclass,"openConnection","()Ljava/net/URLConnection;");

jobject urlconn = env->CallObjectMethod(URLObject, openConnMethod);
```

How do I convert this URLConnection object to HttpURLConnection object?

Answer (score 3):

You don't need to.  Casting doesn't change the actual type of an object, it just lets you refer to it as a different class that it already is (in your example, url.open is returning an HttpUrlConnection.  If it wasn't the cast would throw a ClassCastException.  The type isn't changing you're just referring to it by a more specific type).  In the ndk world, you refer to every java object as a jobject.  So there's never a need to cast them.